# What exactly is a "virtual core" on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, virtualization

The small Standard Instance is:

> Small Instance (Default) 1.7 GB of memory, 1 EC2 Compute Unit (1 virtual core with 1 EC2 Compute Unit), 160 GB of local instance storage, 32-bit or 64-bit platform

Does this mean that you get access to an entire physical CPU core? Or are you sharing a more powerful core with other instances?

Is your performance affected by other people sharing the same ***"physical core"*** or other hardware?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-optimize-cpu.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't get a physical core for a small instance.

"One EC2 Compute Unit provides the equivalent CPU capacity of a 1.0-1.2 GHz 2007 Opteron or 2007 Xeon processor. This is also the equivalent to an early-2006 1.7 GHz Xeon processor referenced in our original documentation." [Amazon EC2 Instance Types](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)

You can run `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to see what hardware you're on.
For example I have a micro instance which has the underlying processor  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz.
From my understanding 40% cpu in top equals 1 Compute Unit. So I can burst to 80% with my 2 Compute Unit's.

Answer (score 15):

this is rough estimate so take it for what its worth. 
Funny enough the micro instance out preformed both the small & medium instances.

I ran Passmark Proformance Test 8.0 on each instance below. 
Each was installed with Windows Server 2008 r2 basic config in Amazon's Virginia based data center.

```
AWS SIZE=======PASSMARK SCORE====SIMILAR SCORED CPU================
t1.micro=======963===============AMD Dual-Core Mobile ZM-80========
m1.small=======384.7=============Intel Celeron M 1.60GHz===========
m1.medium======961===============AMD Dual-Core Mobile ZM-80========
m1.large=======1249==============Intel Core2 Duo T6400 @ 2.00GHz===
m1.xlarge======3010==============AMD Phenom 2 X4 12000=============
m3.xlarge======3911==============Intel Xeon X5365 @ 3.00GHz========
m3.2xlarge=====6984==============Intel Xeon E3-1220 V2 @ 3.10GHz===
```

Currently the m3.2xlarge would cost about $7169 pr year for a reserved instance or $1578 pr month on an on-demand instance.
Most unmanaged dedicated hosting companies I've seen offer Intel Xeon E3-1200 setups for around $2000-2500 pr year.
In my opinion AWS is great for scalability but very costly for anything long-term. 
As seems to be the case with any "cloud" based server systems.

------UPDATE
Here is a great tool for measuring cloud hosting benchmarks.. http://cloudharmony.com/benchmarks

Comment: @JonDog, based on your experience what is not so costly for the longer term?

Comment: @ActionDan Every project has to be evaluated for its specific needs. Some need to be up 24/7, others can run periodically. If you can deal with 99% up time, anything from a shared hosting environment to dedicated servers maybe less expensive. If you require instant scalability or only run periodically, a cloud solution could make it less costly and simplify the process.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html
If look at this table 1 EC2 Compute unit ≈ 350 cpu points

Comment: This article addresses VCPU not vcore if understand correctly

Answer (score 6):

Please go through these blogs to get an idea of virtual cores.Very well explained 
http://www.pythian.com/blog/virtual-cpus-with-amazon-web-services/
http://samrueby.com/2015/01/12/what-are-amazon-aws-vcpus/

Answer (score 0):

According to [this AWS forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=30729), a virtual core equates to a physical CPU core.  Each virtual core can have one or more EC2 Compute Units, depending on the clock speed of the CPU.

Here is a [more detailed analysis](http://gevaperry.typepad.com/main/2009/03/figuring-out-the-roi-of-infrastructureasaservice.html/).

Comment: vCPUs are not the same as the old ECUs. AWS has moved away from specifying ECUs to specifying vCPUs instead.